# is there a way to upload one file then duplicate it to put it in two different repositories

Tags: php, file-upload, copy

Hi I'm trying do put some PHP in my website as a part of it I want my user to be able to add photos on it I already make it work but there is one problem I want the file uploaded to be put in two different repositories here's my code(or the part that as already received the file from the input form this is the part where I move my file into the folders and insert it into my database)  I would like to know how to duplicate the file like that I could put it in two different folders

```
$name=$_FILES['mon_fichier']['name'];
  echo $name."<br/>";
  $destination= './Images/'.$dossierA.'/';
  echo $destination."<br/>";
  // $destinationEN= '../en/Images/';
  $dir = './Images/mainSlider';
  $fichierEtDossiers=scandir($destination);
  for ($i=0; $i<count($fichierEtDossiers); $i++)
  {
          $w = 0;
          while($fichierEtDossiers[$i]==$name){
            $name=explode(".",$_FILES['mon_fichier']['name'])[0]."(".$w.")".".".$extension_upload;
            $w++;
          }
}
  $resultat = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['mon_fichier']['tmp_name'],$destination.$name);
  // $resultat2 = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['mon_fichier']['tmp_name'],$destinationEN.$name);
if ($resultat){
  $req= "INSERT INTO PHOTOS_MONUMENTS(Name, FileName, Valid) VALUES ('".$name."','".$dossierA."',0);";
  try {
    $dbh->query($req);
    echo "<h2 class=\"h2 text-center\">transfer reussi</h2><br />";
    header("Refresh:3; url=upload.php");

  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "<h2 class=\"h2 text-center\">erreur d'enregistrement</h2><br />";
    echo $e;
    header("Refresh:10; url=upload.php");
  }
```

I put in comment what I tried but it don't work, please can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $resultat = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['mon_fichier']['tmp_name'],$destination.$name);

  //$resultat2 = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['mon_fichier']['tmp_name'],$destinationEN.$name);
```

`$_FILES['mon_fichier']['tmp_name']` will be moved to `$destination` after 1st line. 
Try copy it to `$destinationEN`

```
  $resultat2 = copy($_FILES['mon_fichier']['tmp_name'],$destinationEN.$name);
```